# Doubt regarding use of Wick contractions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, vacuum, wick-theorem

I'm currently taking my first course in QFT and am learning about finding transition amplitudes using Wick's theorem. As far as I'm aware, Wick's theorem gives us a way to change from a time-ordered string of operators to a series of normal-ordered strings of operators, which is useful given the form of the S-matrix.

Now I was trying to follow my lecturer's notes on a particular example in a scalar Yukawa theory with real scalar field $\phi$ and complex scalar field $\chi$. In order to compute a particular matrix element, he uses Wick contractions in a way I don't understand, as shown below:

[image]

where $a^\dagger_p$ is the creation operator for a $\chi$ particle and $b^\dagger_p$ is the creation operator for a $\chi$ antiparticle. For some reason he's able to expand the matrix element into a sum of matrix elements with contractions over field operators and creation and annihilation operators, which is something I didn't even know was allowed. Could someone just clarify the principle which this expansion is even allowed? Despite him pointing out "Wick contractions," I'm not sure how Wick's theorem plays a role at all here given that the operator string in the matrix element isn't time ordered.